# How to run a model.fit properly on GPU? (unexptected behaviour)

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, tensorflow2.0, model-fitting

Currently, I am doing y Udemy Python course for data science. In there, there is the following example to train a model in Tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Dropout

model = Sequential()

# Choose whatever number of layers/neurons you want.
model.add(Dense(units=78,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=39,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=19,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))

# https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(x=X_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=3,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1
          )
```

My goal now was to get this to run on my GPU. For that, I altered the last part as follows (the epochs are low on purpose, I just want to see how long it takes per epoch before scaling up):

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    model.fit(x=X_train, 
              y=y_train, 
              epochs=3,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1
              )
```

and for comparison, also as follows:

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    model.fit(x=X_train, 
              y=y_train, 
              epochs=3,
              validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1
              )
```

However, the result is very unexpected: Either, both versions occupy all memory of the GPU but seemingly don't do any calculations on it, and take the exact same time per epoch. Or, the GPU version simply crashes with the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\envs\gpu\lib\site-packages\six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)
 
InternalError:  Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(32, 78), b.shape=(78, 78), m=32, n=78, k=78
     [[node sequential/dense/MatMul (defined at <ipython-input-115-79c9a84ee89a>:8) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_874]
 
Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Sometimes it crashes, sometimes it kind of works but takes as long as the CPU. Sometimes even the CPU version takes 20 sec per epoch, other times it takes 40 sec. The code stays the same, all that changes is that I restart the Kernel in between. I really don't understand it.

When I test the GPU and conda environment using the following code, everything seems to work fine, reproducible and the GPU is about 20x as fast as the CPU:

```
# https://     gist.github.com/ikarus-999/1a845437b454cdfcc1eb5455d373fe63
import sys
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf # compatibility for TF 1 code
from datetime import datetime
 
def test_device (device_name: str):
    shape = (int(10000), int(10000))
    startTime = datetime.now()
    with tf.device(device_name):
        random_matrix = tf.random.uniform(shape=shape, minval=0, maxval=1)
        dot_operation = tf.matmul(random_matrix, tf.transpose(random_matrix))
        sum_operation = tf.reduce_sum(dot_operation)
 
    result = sum_operation
 
    print("Shape:", shape, "Device:", device_name)
    print("—"*50)
    print(result)
    print("Time taken:", datetime.now() - startTime)
    print("\n" * 2)
    
test_device("/cpu:0") # 6 sec
test_device("/gpu:0") # 0.3 sec
```

So, I am sure there is something I am doing wrong.

**TLTR:**

What would be the correct way to call model.fit on the GPU? How can different runs (without changing the code) result in so drastically different outcomes (Crash, vastly different calculation times)?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thx!

Answer (score 4):

After a lot of try and error I finally found a working way to either force CPU or "mixed usage". GPU only doesn't seem to work, though. The with tf.device() method from my original post doesn't seem to do anything in this scenario. I have to hide the GPU if I want to use the CPU, only (Tensorflow 2.1.0):

**CPU only**

```
# force CPU (make CPU visible)
cpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('CPU')
print(cpus)
tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'GPU')  # hide the GPU
tf.config.set_visible_devices(cpus[0], 'CPU') # unhide potentially hidden CPU
tf.config.get_visible_devices()
    
model.fit(x=X_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=25,
          batch_size=256,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1
           )
```

This results in 3-4 sec per epoch and does not tax the GPU.

Restart the Kernel, then:

**GPU only**

```
# force GPU (make GPU visible)
# note: does not work without restarting the kernel, otherwise:
# "Visible devices cannot be modified after being initialized"
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
print(gpus)
tf.config.set_visible_devices([], 'CPU') # hide the CPU
tf.config.set_visible_devices(gpus[0], 'GPU') # unhide potentially hidden GPU
tf.config.get_visible_devices()

model.fit(x=X_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=25,
          batch_size=256,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1
          )
```

That doesn't work as, apparently, the CPU is required by this model:

*"NotFoundError: No CPU devices are available in this process"*

**Default (mixed CPU & GPU):**

Restart the Kernel, then:

```
# test if CPU and GPU are visible
tf.config.get_visible_devices()
# [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
#  PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

model.fit(x=X_train, 
          y=y_train, 
          epochs=25,
          batch_size=256,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1
          )
```

This results in 5-6 sec per epoch, consumes all the RAM of the GPU and uses a small amount of processing power of the GPU (<10%). Apparently, this is slower than using the CPU only for this model (8 GB video RAM vs. 16 GB System RAM??).

If the default mode (CPU & GPU) throws the following error, it seems the GPU is occupied by another process and restarting Windows helps:
*"InternalError: Blas GEMM launch failed"*

There are still lots of mysteries left for me:

- Why is the "mixed" mode slower than CPU only?
- Can you change visible devices without having to restart the Kernel to avoid the following error? *"Visible devices cannot be modified after being initialized"*
- Why does the with tf.device() method not work for this model (no effect), whereas it works for the test_device() code?

If anybody can provide some insight, thank you very much :)

Comment: Don't ask questions in an answer. If you have another question, then ask another question....